# How can a refresh a UITableView to apply new sorting using an NSFetchedResultsController?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Question is pretty clear I guess. I have a UISegmentedControl as my tableViewHeader. I have a selector callback when a segment has been touched. Up on that touch event I would like to reload the tableView using a new NSSortDescriptor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do something like the following when a segment is selected:

```
yourFetchedResultsController.sortDescriptors = // whatever
[NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:yourFetchedResultsController.cacheName]; // if necessary
[yourFetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
[yourTableView reloadData];
```

Comment: There is no such thing yourFetchedResultsController.sortDescriptor

Comment: [[fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];